# Remove specific query string key in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to make a redirect url

**From**

`http://abc.redirect.in/admin/index.php?controller=class&action=add`

**To**

```
http://abc.redirect.in/admin/class/add
```

Any idea?

Want to remove text

> http://abc.redirect.in/admin/`index.php?controller=`class`&action=`add

Comment: Check this out. .htaccess magic examples on Github: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/admin/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/index\.php\?controller=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this. it is giving the pretty url but browser giving me 404 error. On every page I am using $_GET for getting controller and action value.

Comment: test.localhost/admin/index.php?controller=pjAdmin&action=pjActionLogin

Comment: Then these rules should work. Above URL will be redirected to `http://test.localhost/admin/pjAdmin/pjActionLogin` in browser? Are you seeing this pretty URL. Then 2nd rule will route it back `/admin/index.php`. Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess? Or is there any other htaccess?

Comment: No it is not redirecting to pretty url. Yes there is other htaccess as well. This is in root directory. Pretty URL htaccess is in inner directory called admin. Root directory is different framework(Yii).

Comment: It does work for me. Make sure first 302 rule is very first rule in `/admin/.htaccess`